# python minidom xml parser 3

Tags: python, xml, parsing, minidom

```
<student id="1" student:name="robert">
 <sectionA>
  <class name="first"/>
 </sectionA>
</student>
<student id="2" student:name="lucky">
 <sectionB>
  <class name="first"/>
 </sectionB>
</student>
<student id="2" student:name="Dave">
 <sectionA>
  <class name="third"/>
 </sectionA>
</student>


from xml.dom import minidom

dom1 = minidom.parse("file.xml")
student = dom1.getElementsByTagName("student")
for b in student:
    sectionA = dom1.getElementsByTagName("sectionA")
    for a in sectionA:
        name = b.getAttribute("student:name")
        print name
```

This gives me the following output:
    robert
    lucky
    Dave

However I am expecting following output 
Expected Output:
robert
Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line:

```
student = dom1.getElementsByTagName("student")
```

Actually get all items and then always something exists in `a`, then you tried to `getAttribute` from `b`! why `b`?

Perhaps last `for` is completely not necessary, you can use:

```
student = dom1.getElementsByTagName("sectionA")
```

And then get attribute with `parentNode`!

You can use `parentNode()` for example, you can change your code to this:

```
from xml.dom import minidom

dom1 = minidom.parse("file.xml")
student = dom1.getElementsByTagName("sectionA")

for b in student:
  print(b.parentNode.getAttribute("name"))

# Output:
# robert
# Dave
```

Ref: [xml.de](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html#getparent)